# set the value of a django HiddenInput widget to another object's id rendered in the template

Tags: python, django

Imagine we have a detail page for the blog posts of a blog and we accept comments on this page, now we need to know which post we are commenting on, in our views so we can make a comment object for that post.

How is possible to set the `{{ post.id }}` in a HiddenInput widget value so we can then use it in our comment views

I tried to manually add this to my html form but I want to use form template tags so I can validate the form later:

`<input type="hidden" name="post_comment" value="{{post.id}}>`

forms.py:

```
comment_post = forms.Field(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

views.py:

```
def comment(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        Comment.objects.create(text=form.cleaned_data['comment_text'],post=form.cleaned_data['comment_post'] ,cm_author=request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I'd do this by setting the post ID based on something other than a form value. In order to set the post to comment relationship your view has to know which post is being commented on - probably as a URL element - so I'd just use that directly rather than passing it around as form data. Something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def comment(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    # usual form boilerplate below here
```

One way you could implement this in your uris.py is:

uris:

```
url(r'(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', views.comment, name="comment")
```

Depending on the rest of your URL structure it might be clearer to include more context:

```
url(r'post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/comment/$', views.comment, name="comment")
```

But that's basically down to personal preference unless you're aiming for a REST-style API.

There's no need to specify the form action differently - the usual `action=""` will submit the form to a URI that includes the ID, since it's part of the URI that displays the form.

If for some reason you want to do this with the hidden input, use an `initial` argument when creating the form.

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
     form = CommentForm(request.POST, initial={'comment_post': post})
     # usual processing
 else:
     form = CommentForm(initial={'comment_post': post})
 # and render
```

Comment: For the first example, I wouldn't make it a form field at all. I believe it should be possible to create an in-memory `new_comment` instance in a temporarily invalid state, as long as it has a `post` value by the time you try to save it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your model `Comment` has a foreign key relationship with `Post`, you can just use `forms.ModelChoiceField` for `comment_post`:

```
comment_post = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Post.objects.all(),
                                      widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

In the views, give current post object as initial data to the `comment_post`:

```
# assume you have a variable that called "current post"
comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, initial={'comment_post': current_post})
```

Just in case you are not sure what's the behavior, it's going to create a hidden form field and pre-populate selected data with `current_post`, then when you POST the form, the form already contains the data, you call `comment_form.save()` and that's it.

Comment: added `comment_form = CommentForm(initial={'comment_post':current_post})` the single_post_page view so when the views calls the template it populates the value attribute of comment_post hidden field with post's pk.

Comment: and this is the rendered HTML form input: `<input id="id_comment_post" name="comment_post" type="hidden" value="1">`

Comment: but I assume it's not a safe way since users can simply manipulate the HTML form input value and then submit it

Comment: Right - I hesitate to get into web security discussions, because that's an area where I know enough to know I don't know enough to make good recommendations. But in general you can't trust that anything you're getting from the request has not been manipulated - form data, URI, cookies, etc.

Comment: It's true that you could manipulate the data, but your system wouldn't go anything wrong because your form will try to validate when you call `is_valid`. It's the developer's duty to guard the app, otherwise all dropdowns in your app are vulnerable right?

Comment: Sure, neither of our answers get into protecting against manipulation of the input. You'd need at minimum some concept of what posts a user is allowed to comment on, plus validation that the post to be commented on is one of those.